# How to read a png image and transfer to ID2D1Bitmap?

Tags: c++, animation, png, direct2d

I have a C++ project which uses **Windows Animation Manager with Direct2D** under Visual Studio 2010 to implement image sparkled animation.
But when I load a png image, the transparent can’t display correctly.
I use **IWICImagingFactory** and **IWICBitmap** to load the png image, and then create a D2D bitmap from the WIC bitmap.  The **D2D1_PIXEL_FORMAT’s** alphaMode set as **D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED** and format set as **DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM**.  It seems only opaque and transparent without semitranslucent.  And I try to change the D2D1_PIXEL_FORMAT’s alphaMode to **D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_STRAIGHT** but it doesn’t work.
  I also follow the sample code from MSDN ( [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719658(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719658%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ), but nothing display.  Can someone help me that how to load a png image and transfer to ID2D1Bitmap with correct alpha value? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I already solved my question from the example code under *\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Samples\multimedia\wic\wicviewerd2d*. The important keyword is **GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA** when initialize the IWICFormatConverter object.